# How to get the maximum virtual set size of a unix process during its lifetime?

Tags: memory, time, profiling

The `time` command includes a format parameter "M", which according to the `time` man page on Linux is used for the following:

```
Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kilobytes.
```

However, it does not look like `time` is able to measure the maximum virtual set size of a process during its lifetime. How can I achieve this on Linux?

Just to be clear, I have control over the processes being profiled, so if I need to make this child process emit a signal at the end of its execution that indicates it is ready to terminate, so that the parent process can read its VSZ via `ps` or `pmap`, and then have the parent process explicitly terminate the child after the memory has been read, I can do it, but it would be painful, so I was hoping there might be a simpler solution that did not involve instrumenting the code of the program being profiled - something like a drop-in equivalent for `time` that can also measure maximum virtual set size would be ideal. I can write a custom C program to launch the child process, though, if need be. However, if I were to go the C route, I'm not sure what system calls I would use to enable kernel tracing of VSZ in the child process.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT: This turns out to be nontrivial. Possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process/10957355#10957355

Answer (score 1):

Dunno whether it would be useful to you, but `pidstat -r 1 -p 1` samples /sbin/init like this:

```
10:53:38          PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
10:53:39            1      0.00      0.00   13648   1108   0.01  init
10:53:40            1      0.00      0.00   13648   1108   0.01  init
10:53:41            1      0.00      0.00   13648   1108   0.01  init
10:53:42            1      0.00      0.00   13648   1108   0.01  init
10:53:43            1      0.00      0.00   13648   1108   0.01  init
10:53:44            1      0.00      0.00   13648   1108   0.01  init
```

Comment: Do you know if `sysstat` is in LSB?

Comment: @JodieC, no idea, sorry. But this info could be easily fetched from /proc/PID/… for sure (in case).